# Can I load fixtures by specifying a directory in cakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, phpunit

I want to test in php-unit targeting all files in a directory as fixtures .

I realized using fixtures by specifying files individually in a directory.
For example, Class related to User Class under the /user/ directory can be load by inserting following code in test class.

```
public $fixtures = [
        'app.user/user',
        'app.user/user_info',
        'app.user/user_directory',
        ]
```

It's no problem when I have a little fixtures, but in fact I have many related classes should be tested for User class and more than 20 files in Fixtures/user directory.So, I want to load Fixtures specifying directory name only.'app.user/' is fine as example above.
Is it possible?

add_info

I write the following code,and try joining values returned by bellow function to $fixtures array.

```
   public static function fixture_set()
       {
       //some_str_trim extruct fixture prefix excluding absolute path and Fixture.php
       return  array_map(glob(TESTS.'Fixture/Question/*', '/'),some_str_trim);
       }
```

but, $fixtures is static variable, so it's not applied to above function.

Comment: You could overload the constructor or the __get method